# Class Refuses to Inherit Values

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I'm trying to load the XObject (`extends Object`) class, however when I try to log its values it simply comes up as `XObject {}`, even when `util.inspect`ed.

*xobject.js*

```
class XObject extends Object {
  constructor(opts) {
    super(opts);
  }

...

}
```

*application.js*

```
this.xobj = new XObject({ option1: "A", option2: "B" });
logger.debug(`XObject created`, `values = ${require("util").inspect(this.xobj)}`); // prints "DEBUG • XObject instantiated • values = XObject {}"
```

Comment: Where's ```Config``` class?

Comment: Have you tried passing any [options to inspect()](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) ? like showHidden

Comment: @Wainage `Config` is the name I imported as when I `require`d config.js

Comment: @PatrickEvans Passing `{ showHidden: true }` gives me the same result: `Configuration {}`

Comment: You never assigned any properties to your instance. What were you expecting `inspect` to show?

Comment: @JeffM `super(_.config);`

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect some new discoveries — the issue seems to be that `super` isn't working. I can assign other properties to the object, but nothing that should be taken on through `super` simply isn't, no matter what I pass into it.

Comment: I see. I'm leaning toward this being a legit v8 bug, but FF showed the same behavior, so now I'm not so sure. Either way, unless someone else comes up with an answer, you may have to make an issue on v8's github and see what they say. Here's a stripped down version that still reproduces the issue. https://repl.it/LYyC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update (Feb. 2019)**: I submitted this as a v8 bug. Neis on the Chromium said that this behavior is intended; see the discussion here: [v8 issue #8817](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=8817#c5)

---

I ended up figuring out a solution to this issue. Whilst Jeff M, in the comments, suggested this could have been a V8 bug, it is actually acting according to the ECMAScript spec.

The main change is that I am **no longer extending `Object`**.

Here's the concept I've landed on: (code is heavily stripped down and simplified)

```
let inherit = { foo: "bar", baz: 4 };

class TestClass {
  constructor() {
    this.test = "thing";
    // this = TestClass {
    //          test: "thing" }

    Object.assign(this, inherit);
    // this = TestClass { 
    //          test: "thing",
    //          foo: "bar",
    //          baz: 4 }
  }
}
```